# Excel 2013 line chart vs previous excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

in my earlier excel chart I could check the "High-Low Lines" box in the Format Data Series box options tab.  What is the 2013 version equivalent?  I am trying to put the lines on the chart to be vertical instead of hortizontal.  I am constructing a Multivary chart using a line chart.  I could do this in say 1997 or 2003 version.
Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 2):

Select the chart. On the Design ribbon at the very left, click the "Add Chart Element" drop-down and select Lines > High-Low Lines.

[image]

For some unknown reason, this option is not showing under the + button of the selected chart. I think that might be a bug.

Comment: Thank you Teylyn!  I appreciate you help.  It was very useful!

Comment: Please accept my post as the answer, then, as shown in the [Tour](http://superuser.com/tour). That's how to say thanks around here.

Comment: There are already ten items in the '+' icon's dropdown list, and ten seems to be some kind of magic number. I think they could have stretched this one to eleven.